# How locate the Sign in button within https://twitter.com using Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I am writing a script in python that logs in twitter however whenever i try to locate the log-in button in selenium it gives an error

Python code:

```
driver= webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://twitter.com")
login_button= driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//a[@href='/i/flow/signup']")         print(login_button)
```

Source of the target element:

[image: Source of the login button element:]

The error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: //a[@href='/i/flow/signup']
```

I have even tried copying the absolute path of the element:

```
driver= webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://twitter.com")
login_button= driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/div/div/div/div[2]/main/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[3]/a")
print(login_button)
```

This gives the error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: /html/body/div/div/div/div\[2\]/main/div/div/div\[1\]/div\[1\]/div/div\[3\]/a
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As error says: Unable to locate element. You can use wait to "wait" until your element is located. For more you can see: https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html
So you can do that as following code:

```
#import necessary parts
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

#wait
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

#from your code
driver= webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://twitter.com")
login_button = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//a[@href='/i/flow/signup']"))).click() #it will click the button.
```

Answer (score 0):

To click on <kbd>Sign in</kbd> button within [Twitter Login Page](https://twitter.com/)  you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194511/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  driver.get('https://twitter.com/')
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[href='/login'] span > span"))).click()
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  driver.get('https://twitter.com/')    
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='Sign in']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: twitter_signin]